# Differences in R² calculation

Tags: r, statistics

I wasn't sure if I am using the `cor.test` function correctly to calculate Pearson's R², so I did it manually for once and got some slight differences.

I used the `meuse` dataset here to make this issue reproducible:

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
# ordinary kriging:
x <- krige(log(zinc)~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = m)


#1-out Cross Validation
cross<-krige.cv(zinc~1,meuse,m)
cross

# R² Method 1:
RSQR1 <- as.numeric(cor.test(meuse$zinc,cross$var1.pred)$estimate)^2  #Pearson's R Squared

# R² Method 2:
numerator <- c()
for (l in 1:length(meuse$zinc))
{
  numerator[l] <- (meuse$zinc[l] - cross$var1.pred[l])^2
}

denominator  <- c()
for (k in 1:length(meuse$zinc))
{
  denominator[k] <- (meuse$zinc[k] - mean(meuse$zinc))^2
}

RSQR2 <- 1-((sum(numerator))/(sum(denominator)))

# Compare results:
RSQR1
RSQR2
```

Which yields

```
> RSQR1
[1] 0.6281558
> RSQR2
[1] 0.6279801
```

Which is wrong, what did I forget?

Comment: Sorry! It's from the `gstat` package...edited my post.

Comment: My best guess is that you're doing your calculation wrong. I just ran `summary(lm(meuse$zinc ~ cross$var1.pred))$r.squared` and `cor(meuse$zinc, cross$var1.pred)^2` and they both give `0.6281558`. Where did you get your equations from? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) seems like a reasonable place to start. I would suggest looking over your equations . Sorry that I don't have time to look through your equations.